# Oracle users in many to many relationship

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle11g

I am creating a database that would represent a simple videogame inventory where a user would have ownership of certain items. I am looking to form a many to many relationship between the dba_users view and my items table to form a table called userItems.

I've done some research and found that the problem is that dba_users is a view and cannot have a foreign key associated with it.

Do I need to make my own users table and if so, how do I get the usernames to match the dba_users usernames?

Any other way to resolve this? Thank you!

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What does being a database user have to do with your application?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Each item needs to have an owner. That owner would be the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think your relationship will actually be one-to-many/one-to-many through a cross table.
Smth like that:

```
create table item_inventory
( 
item_id varchar2(127),
username varchar2(30), 
constraint fk_inventory_user foreign key (username) references all_users(username),
constraint fk_inventory_item foreign key (item_id) references items(item_id) 
);
```

Comment: This will not work - `all_users(username)` is not  `UNIQUE` . Moreover, for non-dba users, it would say insufficient privileges as `select any dictionary` privilege is not enough to reference a data dictionary table/view.